# Changing the brown color by another color

Tags: beamer, color

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 %\usepackage{etoolbox} (this is necessary for old beamer versions)
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}

\usetheme{Madrid}

% Definition %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{studentbrown}{RGB}{124,71,50}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=studentbrown}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=studentbrown!20!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
        \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to change the brown color by another color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the colour in the command `\definecolor{studentbrown}{RGB}{3,14,159}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 %\usepackage{etoolbox} (this is necessary for old beamer versions)
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}

\usetheme{Madrid}

% Definition %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{studentbrown}{RGB}{3,14,159}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=studentbrown}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=studentbrown!20!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
        \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but please what is the general method?

Comment: @Student This is general, you can use whatever color you want and give it whatever name you like

Comment: I mean how can I know the code of the orange color for example?

Comment: @Student https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/orange-color.html